# how to use colspan in nested table

Tags: html, css, html-table

beginner here, i have a project that requires me to create an html table and insert data to it by columns, and not by rows, I was told that this can be achieved with nested table and the outer table will have one row that every cell in it is a table of its own, my issue with it is that I need the inner cells to colspan according to a variable of their duration and it Does not work on inner tables

my end goal is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21bGB.png)
I have tried to create nested tables and used colspan as follows:

```
  <style>
    th{
        text-align: center;
    }
    table{
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    thursday
                </th>
                <th>
                    wednesday
                </th>
                <th>
                    tuesday
                </th>
                <th>
                    monday
                </th>
                <th>
                    sunday
                </th>
            </tr>
            
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table class="table table-bordered">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table > 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>f</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    
</body>
```

i this possible with nested table? or is there any other method that I need to take like invert the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
This is like Your output image, in this way you don't need nested table

<body>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                thursday
            </th>
            <th>
                wednesday
            </th>
            <th>
                tuesday
            </th>
            <th>
                monday
            </th>
            <th>
                sunday
            </th>
        </tr>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="background:blue">first activity</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background:green" colspan="3">
               second activity
            </td>
            <td>
            
            </td>
            <td>
            
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for your replay ! I am sry I wan't clear enough in my question , in the way that you have shown, I have no way of inserting the data to the table or at least a way that I know of, because without nested table, the rows does not present a specific day